# How do I make the standard Access functions work after a connection to an external database?

Tags: vba, ms-access

The VBA code for external connection has been given to my by our IT-department. I did not wrote it myself.  I just made some adjustments to make it work for my database. I am not an expert. The function `Clear_Analysis` just deletes all records from tabel `tbl_Analysis`.
The function `Analysis_Check` does work in all my other functions. I want to check if a table contains any records.

```
Function Analysis_Check()

    If DCount("*", "tbl_Analysis") = 0 Then

        MsgBox ("No Records!")

    End If
    
        If DCount("*", "tbl_Analysis") <> 0 Then

        MsgBox ("Success!")

    End If
    
End Function
```

But this function does not work anymore after a connection to an external SQL-database.

How do I make this work in the same function?

```
Function Analysis_LIMS()

    Dim objRec
    Dim objConn
    Dim cmdString
    Dim insertString

    Call Clear_Analysis
    
    Set objRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=.....; "
    objConn.Open

    Set localDbConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    localDbConn.ConnectionString = "...;Persist Security Info=False;"
    localDbConn.Open
    cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rapportnaam, t.norm FROM taken t"
    Set objRec = objConn.Execute(cmdString)

    Do While Not objRec.EOF
        insertString = "INSERT INTO tbl_Analysis ([Analysis], [Analysis_Norm]) VALUES ('" & objRec("rapportnaam") & "', '" & objRec("norm") & "')"
        localDbConn.Execute (insertString)
        objRec.MoveNext
    Loop

    Call Analysis_Check

    localDbConn.Close
```

I want to add the call function `Analysis_Check` at the end of function `Analysis_LIMS`

I also tried to make Dcount as a seperate function and call this function at the end of function `Analysis_LIMS`
I can confirm that there are definately records in table `tbl_Analysis`.
But for both methods the Dcount function gives 0 as answer. This is not the case.

If I make a button on the same form which calls function `Analysis_Check`, then function `Analysis_Check` does work. But after that, if I call function `Analysis_Check` through function `Analysis_LIMS` the result is that I get popup message "No Records", I click OK, then comes a second popup message "Success".
If then I do the same thing again, but without using that temporary button it only gives the "No Records" aswer, but there are definately records in `tbl_Analysis`
I have no idea what I am doing wrong or why Access behaves like this. I guess it has something to do with the recordset? Maybe set the recordset to CurrentDb?
Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a timing issue as the query calls will run in another context.

Try either with `DoEvents`:

```vb
Do While Not objRec.EOF
    insertString = "INSERT INTO tbl_Analysis ([Analysis], [Analysis_Norm]) VALUES ('" & objRec("rapportnaam") & "', '" & objRec("norm") & "')"
    localDbConn.Execute (insertString)
    objRec.MoveNext
Loop
DoEvents
```

or use DAO:

```vb
Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tbl_Analysis", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
Do While Not objRec.EOF
    Records.AddNew
        Records!Analysis.Value = objRec("rapportnaam").Value
        Records!Analysis_Norm.Value = objRec("norm").Value
    Records.Update
    objRec.MoveNext
Loop
Records.Close
```

Comment: Completely different answer. I need to learn to read better. :)

Comment: @KostasK.: Welcome to the club!

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I can confirm it is a timing issue. I impemented a 10 second sleep function and then it works. A 1 or 3 second delay does not work. I am going to implement your solution and to make it more efficient. A 10 sec delay is of course not the best solution. I am going to try this asap.

Comment: The DAO method works for me! Thanks again stackoverlow, without your help I would never have solved this issue.